# how to change another text according to dropdown in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, native

**API PART**:

```
{
    "response": "success",
    "fuel_type": [
        {
            "m_type_id": "1",
            "m_fuel_name": "Diesel",
            "m_fuel_price": "98.25"
        },
        {
            "m_type_id": "3",
            "m_fuel_name": "Extra Premium",
            "m_fuel_price": "116.50"
        },
        {
            "m_type_id": "2",
            "m_fuel_name": "Petrol",
            "m_fuel_price": "101.98"
        }
    ]
}
```

[this is drop down and chnage the data according to dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jykwj.png)

[How to change दर according to dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwKku.png)

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post a minimal-reproducible code example so we can help you out.

Answer (score -1):

1. create hook to store the item or index of the selected value from dropdown-

   const [data, setData]=useState([])   // store fuel_type data in
   this state
   const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);  //store index of
   selected item here
2. update the selected state onPress of dropdown element-

   onPress={()=>setSelected(index)}
3. now render your text according to selected value-

   data[selected].m_fuel_price